# Установка Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

После успешного завершения установки Python 3.6 отсутствует папка Scripts. Из-за этого не могу использовать pip, пробовал устанавливать pip через get-pip.py и прочее методы - ничего не помогло. Установил Python 3.7 - всё отлично, но нужен именно 3.6 Windows 8.1, AMD процессор.

Comment: Отсутствует где? Вообще-то и в 3.7, и в 3.6 pip идёт в комплекте с питоном, как-то странно вы устанавливаете значит

Comment: @andreymal, я знаю, что он идёт в комплекте. Перешёл на Windows 8.1 - папка пустая. Был Windows 7 - всё прекрасно устанавливалось.